# Python: using range of indexes of an array in conditions

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

Python newbie here.
Let's say we have an array which contains 10 random integers.
I want to check if each value of the integers is 0<= x <= 9.
So for example somehow like this:

```
if 0 <= n[:11]  <=9:
    print('correct')
```

'n[:10]' is treated like a list so I can't compare it with 0 and 9.
Is there an elegant way to check the range of items in that array?

I don't want to code something like:

```
if 0 <= n[0] and n[1] and ... n[9] <=9:
```

thanks for your help

Comment: `all(0 <= i <= 9 for i in n[:11])`…

Comment: Use a List comprehension, you will have to loop through each element anyways

Answer (score 4):

Check this out:
This returns `True` if and only if ALL of the numbers in the list `n` are at least 0 and at most 9, (in `range(0, 10)`)

```
 all(i in range(0, 10) for i in n)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if 0 <= min(n) <= max(n) <= 9:
```

Could use `and` instead of `<=` in the middle, not sure which I like better.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the check the equality for every elements:

```py
all(0 <= item <= 9 for item in n)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you first sort the list you only have to check the first and last value, like this:

```
sorted_n = sorted(n)

if sorted_n[0] > 0 and sorted_n[-1] < 10:  # returns True or False for whole list
```